# How can a console application sudo itself under OS X  if it needs root privileges?

Tags: macos, privileges, sudo, elevated-privileges

I am wondering if it is possible for a command line application to request root access, like trying to call itself with `sudo`.

I am looking for a solution that would allow to write applications that require `sudo` privileges if it is needed.

It doesn't have to request root access always, only if needed.

Comment: This seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556186/access-private-etc-with-c to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options:

- it could `setuid(0)`, but only if it already has been invoked by root and so has a real UID of 0 and an effective UID of somebody else.
- it could try to `exec` the `sudo` or `su` command and have itself run under UID 0, but only if `sudo` is configured to allow that (which normally requires that the user submit to authentication, as there will be an authorization check).
- it could try to launch a new copy of itself via `AuthorizationExecWithPrivileges()`, but this again requires that the user submit to authn.
- it could have been installed with a `launchd` job that it can communicate with in the system `launchd` context. Communicating with that job would cause `launchd` to invoke it, and presumably it's configured to run under the root user. Now for this to come about, the job needs to have already been deployed: either via an installer (in which case the user authenticated) or via the Service Management framework's `SMJobBless()` API (again, the user will need authentication to approve that).
- it could make use of someone else's badly-written `launchd` job to have that job execute itself with UID 0. As noted, this involves having a badly-written `launchd` job knocking around.

So essentially it is possible, through a number of options, but all of the reliable ones require that the user authenticate and that the tool already be deployed in such a way as it can run in the root context. I actually wrote a whole book about this stuff...see particularly Chapter 6 of [Professional Cocoa Application Security](http://securemacprogramming.com/Secure_Mac_Programming/Home_of_Professional_Cocoa_Application_Security.html).

Notice that all of the options except `setuid` (which I don't recommend you use) actually involved a `fork()` to create a separate process, whether by the calling process or by `launchd`. That means you can actually have two separate executables: one that the user interacts with, and one that performs privileged tasks. That's a better design than putting all of the functionality in one application so I'd recommend that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
su root
# Do things as root here, if authorized
```