# How to running application under root privilege?

Tags: macos, authorization, root, privileges

Please tell me a way grant for my application to modify /Library/Fonts folder as add new and remove font file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- You can split your application into two parts: service(daemon) and UI and install them via installer in the way so your service will have root privileges
- You can run some command from your app using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` but it is deprecated. Still it works
- You can run some command via `NSAppleScript` using "do shell script \"some script\" with administrator privileges". But it more like a hack and [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) says that `NSAppleScript` class must be used only from the main thread of an application. But it works too, and personally I don't have any troubles with that.
- You can create helper tool and use `ServiceManagement.framework` and `SMJobBless()`

You can find some additional info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161602/how-can-a-console-application-sudo-itself-under-os-x-if-it-needs-root-privilege?rq=1)

Comment: Upvote for splitting the app with a helper app. Apple has example code here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: But I build SMJobBless project on XCode 3.2 and Mac OS 10.6 get error 
`
Undefined symbols:
  "_CFBridgingRelease", referenced from:
      -[SMJobBlessAppController blessHelperWithLabel:error:] in SMJobBlessAppController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: See requirements: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: How to authorization grant write to /Library/Fonts folder with AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()

Comment: You are passing your script to `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`. It may be either launch of some your helper script/tool, or just calling the `rm` or `cp` utilities

Comment: I use Mac 10.4 SDK, i try to use kAuthorizationRightExecute = "system.privilege.admin" but not write that folder font. Have a grant as privilege root or not?

Comment: I don't know about 10.4 SDK. And by the way, why do you need /Library/Fonts? Why don't use ~/Library/Fonts? You wouldn't need any specific privileges for this.